# Most efficient way to get the current day in number format?

Tags: vb.net, performance, dayofweek

I have this code to get the current day (e.g. Monday, Tuesday) and convert it to a number format, starting with `saturday = 1`, `monday = 2`, etc.

```
    Dim Current_Day As String = Format(Now, "dddd")
    Dim Day_Name_Val As String = "0"

    Select Case Current_Day
        Case "Saturday"
            Day_Name_Val = "1"
        Case "Monday"
            Day_Name_Val = "2"
        Case "Tuesday"
            Day_Name_Val = "3"
        Case "Wednesday"
            Day_Name_Val = "4"
        Case "Thursday"
            Day_Name_Val = "5"
        Case "Friday"
            Day_Name_Val = "6"
        Case "Sunday"
            Day_Name_Val = "7"
    End Select
```

Is there an efficient or much better way to do this? Maybe a builtin in function of vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default for `DayOfWeek` is:

```
Enum DayOfWeek 
    Sunday = 0
    Monday = 1
    Tuesday = 2
    Wednesday = 3
    Thursday = 4
    Friday = 5
    Saturday = 6
End Enum
```

I would just define your own:

```
Enum MyDayOfWeek 
    Saturday = 1
    Monday = 2
    Tuesday = 3
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 5
    Friday = 6
    Sunday = 7
End Enum
```

That way you can do something like:

```
Dim Day_Name_Val = Convert.ToInt32([Enum].Parse(GetType(MyDayOfWeek),
    DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e9hbgM)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration for this kind of scenarios.

```
  Dim dayNumber As Integer = Now.DayOfWeek()
```

Comment: That's great!, however this is wrong because I still need to use 'Enum' because in that code `friday = 5`, `friday should be = 6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int dayInNumber = (int)Now.DayOfWeek
```

to get the current day as a number. In case of Sunday you may want to do something like

```
 if(dayInNumber == 0){ dayInNumber = 7;}
```

as the enumeration starts from 0

The code is in C# syntax but you can convert it to an equivalent syntax in vb.net